# Evaluate $\int^1_{-1} \frac{P_{l_1}^{m_1}(x)P_{l_2}^{m_2}(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$

Tags: integration, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials, legendre-polynomials

I wish to evaluate $\int^1_{-1} \frac{P_{l_1}^{m_1}(x)P_{l_2}^{m_2}(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} dx$.

There is a neat way to show the integral is zero for certain combinations of ms and ls shown here: 
[Integrating Associated Legendre Polynomials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1265825/integrating-associated-legendre-polynomials)

However I would like to know how to get the rest!

Edit: Ah it reduces to the integral found here [Integration of product of Associated Legendre Polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1929772/integration-of-product-of-associated-legendre-polynomial) by the recurrence formula!